# How to pass model to shared resolver(controller)

Tags: javascript, graphql, sequelize.js, nestjs

I have many resolvers and one abstract resolver from which all will inherit.

How can I pass a model to this abstract resolver? - I need to put it in Query and ResolveField

Below is the code resolver(Users) and resolver(Entity) - Users is inherited from Entity. As well as the entity and users model module

```
@Resolver(() => EntityModel)
export abstract class EntityResolver<M, CMD, UMD> {
  protected constructor(protected service: EntityService<M>) {}

  @RolesGuards([ROLES.USER])
  @ResolveField(() => /* MODEL */)
  @Query(() => /* MODEL */)
  async findAll(): Promise<{ response: M[]; statusCode: number }> {
    return {
      statusCode: HttpStatus.OK,
      response: await this.service.findAll(),
    }
  }
}
```

```
@Resolver(() => Users)
export default class UsersResolver extends EntityResolver<Users, CreateUsersDto, UpdateUsersDto> {
  constructor(protected service: UsersService) {
    super(service)
  }

  @RolesGuards([ROLES.ADMIN])
  @Get('/email/:email')
  async findByEmail(
    @Param('email') email: string,
  ): Promise<{ response: Users; statusCode: number }> {
    return {
      statusCode: HttpStatus.OK,
      response: await this.service.findByEmail(email),
    }
  }
}
```

```
@Module({
  controllers: [UsersController],
  providers: [UsersService, UsersResolver],
  imports: [SequelizeModule.forFeature([Users]), RolesModule, LoggerModule],
  exports: [SequelizeModule, UsersService],
})
export class UsersModule {}
```

```
@ObjectType()
export class EntityModel<M, MCA = {}> extends Model<M, MCA> {
  user_id: string;
}
```

```
interface UserCreationAttrs {
  id: string
  email: string
  password: string
}


@ObjectType()
@Table({ tableName: 'Users' })
export class Users extends EntityModel<Users, UserCreationAttrs> {
  @Column({
    type: DataType.STRING,
    unique: true,
    primaryKey: true,
  })
  id: string

  @Column({ type: DataType.STRING, unique: true, allowNull: false })
  email: string

  @Column({ type: DataType.STRING, allowNull: false })
  password: string

  @BelongsToMany(() => Roles, () => UsersRoles)
  roles: Roles[]

  @HasMany(() => Funds)
  funds: Funds[]

  @HasMany(() => Expense)
  expense: Expense[]

  @HasMany(() => ExpenseCategories)
  expenseCategories: ExpenseCategories[]

  @HasMany(() => Income)
  income: Income[]

  @HasMany(() => IncomeCategories)
  incomeCategories: IncomeCategories[]
}
```

I tried to pass the model through the constructor, but for some reason I was told that the model could be undefined.